# Yii2 customize radioList button

Tags: php, html, forms, yii2, radiobuttonlist

How to customize the look and feel of yii2 radio list button.

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'gender')->radioList(array('1' => 'One', 2 => 'Two'), array('template' => "<td>{input}</td><td>{label}</td>")); ?>
```

I need to get the required sign only on Gender label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check your css rules (not yii2 or bootstrap, yours) since there is no such rules by default in yii2/bootstrap.

You could simply use :

```
.form-group.required label.control-label:after {
    content: " *";
    color: #a94442;
}
```

Comment: I prefer the color that the offical documentation tells: red. (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-forms.html)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can trick what is displayed with some CSS ? You can hide the stars for the radio buttons and keep the one on the field ?

I don't know the exact HTML generated (can you provide the html), so it's hard to give an example of the CSS. Maybe something like

```
FIELD LABEL .star {display:none;}
```

or maybe (really depends on the HTML/CSS generated by Yii2)

```
FIELD LABEL::after {content:"";}
```